# How do I add fingerprint authentication to Mern Stack web App (an Employee Attendance Management System)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, fingerprint

I'm working on a project to manage the attendance of employees in an organization. As part of this web-based project, employees must mark their attendance after biometric authentication (through fingerprints). I'm using React or Angular as the frontend, NodeJS as the backend, and MongoDB as the database. What are the best ways to authenticate employees using their fingerprints? (fingerprints will be taken by built-in fingerprint scanners in laptops or External Scanners).

Suggest any NPM package or something. (Any video tutorials would be very helpful.)

Comment: what is your frontend running through? Is it through a browser via a website? Electron? Windows Store app?

Comment: A lot of this will depend on what software the app is running on AND how the built in fingerprint scanner works.

Comment: You might be looking for WebAuthN -- https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/16/biometric-authentication-for-web-devs/

Comment: basically, it is web-based project so it runs on browser. and mostly it will use external fingerprint Scaner.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.